# android_app_chooser build error

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed this article.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android

When I did 'rosmake android_app_chooser', I got the error message as below.

How can I solve this problem?

```
BUILD FAILED
  /opt/rocon_elec/android/android_gingerbread/build.xml:4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
  /opt/rocon_elec/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/android.xml:46: taskdef class com.android.ant.AaptExecLoopTask cannot be found
   using the classloader AntClassLoader[/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/anttasks.jar:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/common.jar:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/sdklib.jar:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/androidprefs.jar:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/mkidentity.jar:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/commons-compress-1.0.jar:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/httpcore-4.1.jar:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/httpmime-4.1.1.jar:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar]
```

build environment :

```
ubuntu 11.04 natty
Ant 1.8.1
android SDK : android-sdk_r14-linux.tgz
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11686/android_app_chooser-build-error/) by [hughie](https://answers.ros.org/users/232/hughie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hughie](https://answers.ros.org/users/232/hughie/) on 2011-10-27**:
Hi, Yes, I extracted [${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/anttasks.jar] file($sdk.dir=/opt/android-sdk-linux, rosjava_bootstrap/android.xml) and checked. Thank you for your concern.

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2011-10-27**:
Sorry, just to be clear. You checked the jar file that is listed first in the classpath for the class AaptExecLoopTask.class?

**Comment by [hughie](https://answers.ros.org/users/232/hughie/) on 2011-10-26**:
There is [/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/anttasks.jar] file. and the jar file has AaptExecTask.class. but the error message show this message in verbose mode. [ Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.ant.AaptExecLoopTask ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is actually due to a change in the new version of Android tools. You'll have to fix rosjava_bootstrap/android.xml to make this work. See http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=70

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2011-11-09**:
FYI, this is now fixed.